# Stop another app's background audio on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, background

How do I stop background audio from another app?

I have tried

```
NSError *error;  
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];  
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options` and `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *) application` but to no effect.

My app plays audio using the The Amazing Audio Engine but does not require background audio itself, so I do not want to add the "audio" key to "Required Device Capabilities" in info.plist

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the [answer from Michael Tyson of The Amazing Audio Engine](http://forum.theamazingaudioengine.com/discussion/459/stop-another-app039s-background-audio) over on his forum.

```
UInt32 allowMixing = NO;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof (allowMixing), &allowMixing);
```

or if you're using The Amazing Audio Engine:
`audioController.allowMixingWithOtherApps = NO;`

(Seems like this should be set to NO by default depending on which audio session you use, however that was not the case with The Amazing Audio Engine)

Answer (score 2):

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil];` solve the problem

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in my iOS application and got it resolved through 'Bamsworld's solution. Check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801775/stop-background-audio-while-starting/20802024?noredirect=1#comment31188755_20802024) for the detailed information.

The solution:
Try this in your appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // set audio session category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord with no options
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"setCategoryError");
    }

    // set audio session mode to default
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"setModeError");
    }

    // activate audio session
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"activationError");
    }
    // ... etc.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, out of curiosity in providing the solution, I gave the link.