# Stop Background audio while starting

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession, foreground

I could make the application, to play the audio when it moves to the background, by adding the setting in info.plist file.

But, when some other iOS application plays background audio, and when the current application comes to foreground, how to stop the background audio invoked by other  application?

Comment: Are you talking about an iOS app?

Comment: yes, in iOS application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at AVAudioSession class and AVAudioSession programming guide by Apple.
This will hopefully steer you in the right direction.

To stop background audio when your application starts set your audio session to a non-mixable category and mode then set active.

If you don't configure an audio session your application will get the default session which in your case is not what you're after.

Try this in you applicationDelegates method - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

```
// set audio session category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord with no options
success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"setCategoryError");
}

// set audio session mode to default
success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"setModeError");
}

// activate audio session
success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"activationError");
}
```

Comment: I'm using audiotoolbox framework for playback/recording. Without switching to AVAudioSession is it possible?

Comment: You don't switch to AVAudioSession. Every application in iOS has an audio session object that your application can configure. It uses a singleton pattern and is used to state your applications 'intentions' as to how you want to 'play with others'.

Comment: great!! after making 'setActive:NO' in your given code, I got the requirement fullfilled. It is working as expected.I tried 'AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &size, &audioIsAlreadyPlaying);' for detecting. But it could not stop the background audio. Your solution is cool.

Comment: Thank you, glad you liked. Extra note:- to detect background audio (from iOS 6.0) check the BOOL property [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].otherAudioPlaying

Comment: Sorry, again it seems to be not stopping the playback audio, when some other audio app comes to the foreground. any idea?

Comment: Taking care of the notifications and initial setup verification resolved the issue, that I mentioned in the previous comments. Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at Audio Session Programming Guide -> Audio Session Basics -> How the System Resolves Competing Audio Demands [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Basics/Basics.html). This explains whats going on with your app. Hope this helps.